# Find the first string that not start with special character("@[")

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find the first occurrence of given string ("name") that not started with "@[".

```
var str="@[name](com.domain.company:66) my name and another name"
```

I used the `pattern=/[^@\[]name/`

This return the correct match but with space before the specific string
I.e return " name" (the one after "my")

How can I get only the string "name" without space at the beginning?

Comment: why not trim what you get something like `" sad".trim()`

Comment: You want to find a word in this string which contains a specific text, `name` for example, which doesn't start with `@`, right? What do you want to do with it then, just curios

Comment: replace it with another string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample input, how about "The first ocurrence of `name` after the the first occurence of a closing paren":

```
/(\).*?)name/
```

You can use `$1` in a replacement to retain whatever leads up to the string `name`.

```
str.replace(/(\).*?)name/, "$1foo");

// -> "@[name](com.domain.company:66) my foo and another name"
```

---

The full form that properly recognizes the `@[...](...) ...` construct would look like this:

```
/(@\[[^\]]+\]\([^)]+\)(?:(?!@\[)[\s\S])*?)name/
```

It would be used in the same way as above, but it can cope correctly with multiple occurrences in a longer text.

Comment: this works fine ,but when the name start in new line the pattern doesn't match it .
var str="@[name](com.domain.company:66)
my name and another name"
I tried this one but not work ,/(\).*?\n?)name/

Comment: Use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` - or use the second pattern straightaway.

Answer (score 0):

if it is not mandatory to use regex then try this method

```
var str="@[name](com.domain.company:66) my name and another name";
var result = str.split( /\s/ ).reduce( function(prev,current){
  if ( current.indexOf( "name" ) != -1 && current.indexOf( "@[" ) != 0 )
  {
    return current;
  }
  return prev;

} );
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex groups, for example:

```
yourString.match(/[^@\[](name)/)[1];
```

`[1]` means get the string inside the 1st group ( inside `(` and `)`)

Answer (score 0):

if the name after @ is always inside [] you can use this:

```
var str="@[name](com.domain.company:66) my name and another name";

var reg = /[^@\[][^\]]+/;

console.log(str.match(reg)[0]); //prints name
```